# Moving MySQL files from cloned disk to new server

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to move MySQL files from `/var/lib/mysql` to an active server (Ubuntu). Unfortunately, my old server broke and I did not have time run `mysqldump`. When I moved the whole directory with the different db directories, MySQL refuses to restart. The version I am copying from used to be 5.5.26 and the one installed on the server is 5.5.58, could this be culprit? I am running Ubuntu, and the same was running on the the old server. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: And how is this question related to programming? This is a pure admin issue. DBA or serverfault forums would be a lot better place for this question. This question is probably already answered there, just you need to add the table type (innodb / myisam / etc) to your search criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comment, I have asked the same question in one of the sites you suggested. Any clues as to how to add the table type to my search criteria when mysql does not start?

Comment: I suggest typing, but if you use voice searching, then you can speak the necessary table type.

Comment: funny but unhelpful, I am afraid.

Comment: I figured out, after moving files I had forgotten to reassign permission to mysql: chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql. Now everything works fine.